# Is it defined what will happen if you shift a float?

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-shift

I am following [This video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYRrGTC7GtA) to implement a raycaster. It contains this code:

```
if(ra > PI) { ry = (((int)py>>6)<<6)-0.0001; rx=(py-ry)*aTan+px; yo=-64; xo=-yo*aTan; }//looking up
```

I hope I have transcribed this correctly. In particular, my question is about casting `py` (it's declared as `float`) to integer, shifting it back and forth, subtracting something, and then assigning it to a `ry` (also a `float`) This line of code is entered at time 7:24, where he also explains that he wants to

> round the y position to the nearest 64th value

(I'm unsure if that means the nearest multiple of 64 or the nearest (1/64), but I know that the 6 in the source is derived from the number 64, being 2⁶)

For one thing, I think that it would be valid for the compiler to load (say) a 32-bit float into a machine register, and then shift that value down by six spaces, and then shift it back up by six spaces (these two operations could interfere with the mantissa, or the exponent, or maybe something else, *or* these two operations could be deleted by a peephole optimisation step.)

Also I think it would be valid for the compiler to make demons fly out of your nose when this statement is executed.

So my question is, is `(((int)py>>6)<<6)` defined in C when `py` is `float`?

Comment: The `float` is first cast to integer, so "if you shift a float" is not relevant. Having truncated any fractional value, it is shifted another 6 bits, and then shifted back, which will replace all those l.s bits with a `0`. They might have well have used `&` with a mask instead of shifting twice.

Comment: @WeatherVane That seems like an answer to me, not a comment ☺

Comment: Dude - the premise of your question is wrong.  The code you cited is shifting an *INTEGER*, not a float.   Weather Vane's response was both correct and appropriate.  He doesn't need to make an "answer" to tell you that you're "asking the wrong question".

Comment: Strictly speaking, the twice-shifted `int` is converted to `double` before the subtraction (because `0.0001` is a `double` value) and is then again converted to `float` to be asigned to the original `float` variable. In these days leading up to the 22nd century please throw away the obsolete 20th century books and always use `double` unless you have a compelling reason to use `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is `(((int)py>>6)<<6)` defined in C when `py` is `float`?

It is certainly *undefined behavior* (UB) for many `float`.  The cast to an `int` is UB for `float` with a whole number value outside the `[INT_MIN  ... INT_MAX]` range.

So code is UB for about 38% of all [typical `float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) - the large valued ones, [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)s and infinities.

---

For typical `float`, a cast to `int128_t` is defined for nearly all `float`.

---

To get to OP's goal, code could use the below, which I believe to be well defined for all `float`.

If anything, use the below to assess the correctness of one's *crafted code*.

```
// round the y position to the nearest 64th value
float round_to_64th(float x) {
  if (isfinite(x)) {
    float ipart;
    // The modf functions break the argument value into integral and fractional parts
    float frac = modff(x, &ipart);
    x = ipart + roundf(frac*64)/64;
  }
  return x;
}
```

---

"I'm unsure if that means the nearest multiple of 64 or the nearest (1/64)"

On review, OP's code is attempting to truncate to the nearest multiple of 64 or 2⁶.

It is still UB for many `float`.

Answer (score 1):

That code doesn't shift a `float` because the bitshift operators aren't defined for floating-point types. If you try it you will get a compiler error.

Notice that the code is `(int)py >> 6`, the `float` is cast to an `int` before the shift operation. The integer value is what is being shifted.

If your question is "what will happen if you shift a float?", the answer is it won't compile. [Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/-UzNyN).

Comment: Yes. Of course, `(int)py` is an integer, regardless of how `py` is declared. And  `(((int)py>>6)<<6)-0.0001` is a float, I'm pretty sure. The question is if the behaviour is defined (and implied, does the code match the intention)

Comment: The subtraction `-0.0001` is defined, the twice-shifted integer is converted back to floating point before the subtraction.

Comment: @Wilson There is no `float` shift operator. In that expression the `float` value is **cast** to an `int`, the integer value is shifted right then left, and a floating-point value is then subtracted. At no point is there a floating-point shift performed.

Comment: Re "*The question is if the behaviour is defined*", Yes, shifting an `int` is defined. (I'm not sure if it's defined when shifting by `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BITS` or more, but that's not the case here.)

Answer (score -3):

The best possible recreation of the shift ops for floating points, in short, without using additional functions are the following:

```
Left shift:
ShiftFloat(py,6,1);

Right shift:
ShiftFloat(py,6,0);

float ShiftFloat(float x, int count, int ismultiplication)
{
    float value = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        value *= (powf(0.5,(float)(ismultiplication^1)) / powf(2.0,(float)(ismultiplication)));
    }
    return count != 0 ? value : x;
}
```

Comment: "Best possible"?  The original code was probably angling for raw speed, which those calls to `powf` are probably going to get in the way of.  Also, did you mean to multiply and divide by 36, or 64?

Comment: Revised the code a bit, it was supposed to divide/multiply by 24 after shift.

Comment: "Best possible?" Ridiculous.  If I wanted to perform such a shift with strictly-conforming code, I would use a combination of [`frexpf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/frexp), manipulation of the resulting (binary) exponent, and [`ldexpf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ldexp).  That uses only standard library functions (two function calls *total* for a shift of any length), is exact as long as there is no over- or underflow, and can be expected to be extremely fast.

Comment: Or if I was prepared to assume that `FLT_RADIX` was 2, (not guaranteed, but true for a very wide variety of implementations) then I would probably just use [`scalbnf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scalblnf).